# jQuery count characters rather than text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to count characters rather than text? I limited 30 words, how to limit 30 characters 
Thanks a lot.

```
function excerpt(str, nwords) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    words.splice(nwords, words.length - 1);
    return words.join(' ') + '&hellip;';
}

var $div = $('.container');
$div.each(function() {
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($(this).text(), 30);
    $(this).data('html', $(this).html()).html( theExcerpt );
});

$('span').click(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
    var $div = $(this).prev();
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($div.text(), 30);
    $div.html( isHidden ? $div.data('html') : theExcerpt);
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

Herer ist the snippet http://jsfiddle.net/Nh4K2/

Comment: `string_length = str.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function excerpt(text, len) {
    return text.substring(0, len)+"&hellip;";
}
```